# Solving the following recurrence relation

Tags: algorithms, recurrence-relations, computational-complexity, recursive-algorithms

I have a recurrence relation, it is like the following:

$$
T(e^n) = 2\cdot T(e^{n-1}) + e^n, \text{ where $e$ is the natural logarithm}
$$

To solve this and find a Θ bound, i tried the following: I put k=e<sup>n</sup>, and the equation transforms into:
$$
T(k)=2\cdot T(k/e)+k
$$
Then, i try to use the master theorem. According to master theorem, $a=2, b=e>2 $ and $f(k)=k$. So, we have the case where $f(k)=\Omega(n^{log_a b  + \epsilon})$ for some $\epsilon$>0, thus we have $T(k)=\Theta (f(k))= \Theta(k)$. Then put $k=n$, we have $T(n)=\Theta(n)$. Does my solution have any mistakes?Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks fine to me. Even better, you can plug $T(k)=2T(k/e)+k$ directly in Wolfram Alpha to get an exact answer.